# SSIS CDC with Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I was wondering if I can use SSIS, as an ETL tool to extract data from Oracle 11g and load it to another Oracle 11g destination, and apply CDC. I have used SSIS CDC with MS SQL; however, I had to enable CDC on the database so I was wondering if I can do the same thing.

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-service-for-oracle-by-attunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the following Microsoft Docs Topics to learn more on *Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Change Data Capture for Oracle by Attunity*

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7644.microsoft-sql-server-2012-change-data-capture-for-oracle-by-attunity-topics.aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-service-for-oracle-by-attunity

This link contains helpful information on how to setup and use this component. so i think this is what you are looking for.

Also to work with oracle using SSIS 2012 you have to download the oracle connectors:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is really useful. However, I am stuck at enabling CDC with Oracle 11g as our DBA says that we don't have a "stream". So Is it possible to apply this when we don't have a stream?

Comment: @user2597012 really sorry, i don't have a good experience in SSIS, i don't know exactly if that can be done.